# spresense バッテリ駆動時のweak battery judgment voltage(PMIC：CXD5247GF)について

Tags: spresense

spresenseをバッテリ駆動する際に推奨電圧3.6～4.4Vとなってますが、データシートをみる限り3.3Vでも駆動すると思われます。しかし、3.4V未満にした際に停止してしまいます。おそらくpmicのweak battery judgment voltageによるものだと思うのですが、この設定値を変更する方法を教えていただきたいです。
(CXD5247GFのデータシートではレジスタで可変可能と記載ありました。)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-nuttx/blob/new-master/arch/arm/src/cxd56xx/cxd56_pmic.h#L466

```c
/****************************************************************************
 * Name: cxd56_pmic_setlowervol
 *
 * Description:
 *   Set lower limit of voltage for system to be running.
 *
 * Input Parameter:
 *   voltage - Lower limit voltage (mV)
 *
 * Returned Value:
 *   Return 0 on success. Otherwise, return a negated errno.
 *
 ****************************************************************************/

int cxd56_pmic_setlowervol(int voltage);
```

`cxd56_pmic_setlowervol`関数で設定できるようです。引数はミリボルト単位なので、例えば`3.0V`に設定するときは、`cxd56_pmic_setlowervol(3000);`のように指定します。実際に試してみたら`3.3V`以下のバッテリーでも電源が落ちなくなりました。

ただ、当たり前ですが3.3V LDOなど諸々動作しなくなるので限定的な用途でしか使えないとは思います。
参考まで。

Comment: 動作確認できました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 素晴らしい。もしお役に立ったなら「承認済み」マークを付けてもらえるとうれしいです^^