# SPRESENSEの電池駆動について

Tags: spresense

小型化するためにSPRESENSEの給電方法を模索しています。
現在はリチウムポリマー電池で給電しているのですが、SPRESENSEは乾電池でも動くということなので、推奨電圧になるべく近づけボタン電池で駆動を試みましたが、動作が安定しません。

SPRESENSEを乾電池やボタン電池での給電方法、または小型化できるような給電方法などがありましたら、アドバイスをいただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

使用した電池ボックス
https://www.akiba-led.jp/product/1631
https://akizukidenshi.com/catalog/g/gP-12666/

Comment: 既読かもしれませんが、この辺の記事が何か参考になるかも。[「乾電池で動くSPRESENSE」は本当に乾電池(ボタン電池)で動くのか？](https://qiita.com/nara256/items/f9de17423967724f0fb3), [SPRESENSE の Low Power ライブラリをバッテリー給電で試してみた！　\[SPRESENSE\]](https://makers-with-myson.blog.ss-blog.jp/2019-12-08), [spresense バッテリ駆動時のweak battery judgment voltage(PMIC：CXD5247GF)について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/83656/26370), [SPRESENSEの消費電力を可視化して解析](https://www.aps-web.jp/academy/amp/10632/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPRESENSEに限らずですが、Arduino系のボードを動かすときに、9Vの乾電池をLDOでドロップさせて使うことをよくやります。ただし、電池はアルカリ乾電池がよいです。マンガン電池は放電電流が少ないので避けたほうがよいです。

もう一つ、1.5Vのアルカリ乾電池２本（３V）をDCDCで昇圧する方法もあります。電池ケースを使いたい場合はこの手をよく使います。

もし電子工作はごめんだという場合は、SPRESENSEであれば1.5Vのアルカリ乾電池３本（4.5V）でもギリ動かせると思います。

お使いのボタン電池は、標準放電電流が200uA程度と腕時計や体温計、RTCのバックアップ電源などの超低消費電力用途向けです。いくら低消費電力のSPRESENSEでもメインボードだけで数mAは消費するので厳しいと思います。

それでもという場合は、アルカリボタン電池のLR系であれば最大放電電流が大きそうなのでいけるかも知れません。でも、容量が少ないので電池はすぐになくなるでしょう。一方、SR系やCR系は長持ち重視の電池なので、そもそも駆動するのが難しいように思います。

Answer (score 2):

チップワンストップにこのような回路があります。
昇圧回路が付いているので、これを使うと電池の電圧降下に対して対応ができ、
電池を使いきれるようです。

こちらを使ってみるか、マネして回路を組んでみてもよいかもしれません。

ご参考まで。

https://www.chip1stop.com/view/dispDetail/DispDetail?partId=PATA-0000003&keyword=Spresense

SPRESENSE用3.7V電源基板
https://p-art.net/wp2/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/pamphlet-powerboard_PSB01.pdf

Answer (score 0):

消費電流の問題です
そもそも電池は、ある程度の電流が流れると電圧が下がり、その結果、動作が不安定となります
ボタン電池は電流容量が小さいため、極力電流消費を少なくする必要があります
SPRESENSEってのはどんなものかは知りませんが、電源表示のLEDなどがついている場合は、それが無駄な電流消費となるため、外してしまう必要があります